# Connect to an irc server with password

Tags: irc, mirc

I'm writing script in `remote.ini` The script looks like

```
on 1:start:{
    server some.irc.server
    server -m another.irc.server
}
```

The script works well as when I open mIRC, it automatically connect to 2 servers above

Now, I want to connect to an irc server that require password, say `abcdef`

How can I write script in `remote.ini` to connect to this server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for `/server` in mIRC is:

```
/server [-emnsarpfoc] <server/groupname> [port] [password] [-i nick anick email name] [-jn #channel pass]
```

So, try:

```
on 1:start:{
    server some.irc.server
    server -m another.irc.server
    server -m third.irc.server 6667 abcdef
}
```